# Confused about compile_path in elixir's mix.exs

Tags: elixir

I am confused about the `compile_path` setting in mix.exs. With a setting like below:

```
defmodule MyProject.Mixfile do
use Mix.Project

def project do
[ app: :my_project,
  version: "0.0.1",
  elixir: "~> 0.12.0",
  deps: deps,
  escript_main_module: MyProject,
  compile_path: "ebing/ew/ebin"]
end

# Configuration for the OTP application
def application do
  []
end

# Returns the list of dependencies in the format:
# { :foobar, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/foobar.git", tag: "0.1" }
#
# To specify particular versions, regardless of the tag, do:
# { :barbat, "~> 0.1", github: "elixir-lang/barbat" }
defp deps do
  []
end
end
```

With the compile_path and after running `mix compile` I still cannot find the directory ebing/we/ebin. I also tried making the directory first but then it is still empty. I also tried `mix compile --force` and it still builds in the default directory.

Can someone help with the understanding of the `compile_path` setting ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `:compile_path` option is no longer supported. Mix will always compile to `_build`.

Comment: Is there a reason why that was deprecated? I want/need the ability to specify where to build to.